# Find an example of open / closed discontinuous function

Tags: general-topology

I wondered if we can find a closed discontinuous map f: ℝ --> ℝ
and can such a map also not be open ?

and is there also a open discontinuous map ?

i'm thinking about it since a couple of hours but cant imagine one, maybe someone can help me?

Thanks for help

Comment: See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301460/an-example-of-an-open-discontinuous-function)

Comment: Yes , thank you ! but i need also one for a closed map

Comment: That's considerably easier,  I think you can do that case on your own.  Hint:  look for a function such that the image of *every* set is closed.